# TYPO3: Extend ctype textmedia with subheader

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to add the subheader to the ctype 'textmedia' (TYPO3 9.5 & 10.4).
I followed this stackoverflow answer:
[TYPO3 8 show layout selection in backend preview for textmedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944156/typo3-8-show-layout-selection-in-backend-preview-for-textmedia)
to register my Hook

```
typo3conf/ext/my-extension/Classes/Hooks/PageLayoutView/TextMediaCustomPreviewRenderer.php
```

Then I added the subheader

```
 <?php
namespace aaa\bbb\Hooks\PageLayoutView;
   
use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView;

/**
 * Contains a preview rendering for the page module of CType="textmedia"
 */
class TextMediaCustomPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{
    /**
     * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element of type "textmedia"
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
     * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionality
     * @param string $headerContent Header content
     * @param string $subheaderContent Subheader content
     * @param string $itemContent Item content
     * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
     */
    public function preProcess(
        PageLayoutView &$parentObject,
        &$drawItem,
        &$headerContent,
        &$subheaderContent,
        &$itemContent,
        array &$row
    ) {
        if ($row['CType'] === 'textmedia') {
            if ($row['bodytext']) {
                $itemContent .= $parentObject->linkEditContent($parentObject->renderText($row['bodytext']), $row) . '<br />';
            }

            if ($row['assets']) {
                $itemContent .= $parentObject->linkEditContent($parentObject->getThumbCodeUnlinked($row, 'tt_content', 'assets'), $row) . '<br />';

                $fileReferences = BackendUtility::resolveFileReferences('tt_content', 'assets', $row);

                if (!empty($fileReferences)) {
                    $linkedContent = '';

                    foreach ($fileReferences as $fileReference) {
                        $description = $fileReference->getDescription();
                        if ($description !== null && $description !== '') {
                            $linkedContent .= htmlspecialchars($description) . '<br />';
                        }
                    }

                    $itemContent .= $parentObject->linkEditContent($linkedContent, $row);

                    unset($linkedContent);
                }
            }

            $drawItem = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the errror:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of aaaa\bbb\Hooks\PageLayoutView\TextMediaCustomPreviewRenderer::preProcess(TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$subheaderContent, &$itemContent, array &$row) must be compatible with TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface::preProcess(TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row) in /kunden/1111/rp-hosting/2222/333/typo3cms/projekt1/typo3conf/ext/my-sitepackage/Classes/Hooks/PageLayoutView/TextMediaCustomPreviewRenderer.php on line 23
```

What do I have to do to make it compatible with

```
TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface::preProcess(TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it a bit wrong. You do not add the subheader in your `process()` arguments. In general, the arguments must be the same as the class that they extend. You can add the subheader inside the  `if ($row['CType'] === 'textmedia') {}` by adding the value in the `itemContent`

```
$itemContent .= $row['subheader'];
```

Personally i would avoid to do it this way. My preferred choice is to call the StandAlone View and assign a template for preview. Is easier to maintain and program it.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect for me. Can you give me a hint how to call the StandAlone View?

Comment: I've got a problem when textmedia has pictures 'Class 'aaa\bbb\Hooks\PageLayoutView\BackendUtility' not found | Error thrown in file /xxx/yyy/rp-hosting/ZZZ/aaa/typo3cms/projekt1/typo3conf/ext/my-extension/Classes/Hooks/PageLayoutView/TextMediaCustomPreviewRenderer.php in line 39'

Comment: I could solve it by adding 'BackendUtility.php' to the folder and changing the namespace